# getting oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwUnsupportedFeatureSqlException error

Tags: jdbc, java-7, oracle9i, sqlexception

I'm getting the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException:
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:269)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwUnsupportedFeatureSqlException(DBError.java:689)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.createStatement(OracleConnection.java:3224)
```

and this is pointing to the following line of Code :

```
ResultSet resultSet = getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY, ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT ).executeQuery(Request.getEtat());
```

This is mostly because of some unsupported feature in my environment, so what is the problem exactly with my snippet of code ?
Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Apart from the fact that your code is leaking resources, I don't see anything obviously wrong. Which version of the driver are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT` is only supported with Oracle 10g 10.2.0 and higher with the Oracle JDBC driver 10.2.0 or higher. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/overvw.htm#JJDBC28045 :

> Feature | Server-Side Internal | JDBC OCI | JDBC Thin
>   ...
>   JDBC 3.0 Holdable Cursors | 10.2.0 | 10.2.0 | 10.2.0

As you indicate you are using Oracle 9i, the feature doesn't work and an exception is thrown. And as the exception is `SQLException` and not `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`, I  assume you are using an old driver as well.